Query to Return List of Items that DO NOT have child
I am trying to create a query for Overdue Work Items. We have a process to create a "Child" Link when a task becomes overdue. So I want to query for any items that are Overdue but the user HAS NOT yet created the "Child" Work Item. I cannot use link count because that number varies, We use Successor and Predecessor relationships as well so when I try to use work items and direct links it returns the direct links as well. I only want to see "Active" Work Items, that are overdue, that do not have a child.
I have tried using the different query types but I can't find a way to Exclude the overdue task that has a "Child". I can query and find all the tasks that do have a "Child", but I want the list to only include items that Don't.
